# Java web project get HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error and The import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.resources cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I can not run my java web project. I got `HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error` from the web and `The import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.resources cannot be resolved` from the eclipse

After I downloaded a web project from GitHub and made some configurations, the project can run successfully. But as soon as I try to connect the web to MySQL, that is the function of login. The web went wrong. And I got this

```
Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.ascent.dao.LoginDAO.login(LoginDAO.java:40)
com.ascent.servlet.LoginServlet.userLogin(LoginServlet.java:183)
com.ascent.servlet.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:39)
com.ascent.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:31)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:682)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:765)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.ascent.util.ChangeCharsetFilter.doFilter(ChangeCharsetFilter.java:22)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

And the eclipse has an error`` `The import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.resources cannot be resolved` ``and plenty of warnings such as `` 'pst' is not closed at this location LoginDAO.java` ``.
The code of the project seems correct because my friends can log in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`'pst' is not closed at this location LoginDAO.java` means that you have resources which is not closed, such as a database connection etc. You should close it after use, the code below:

```java
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url:"url", user:"root", password:"password");
con.close();
```

It is more common to maintain a connection pool of database, such as [hikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

`The import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.resources cannot be resolved` I think your code import duplicate package, you can check your code again. Hope the answer helps you!